Nit picking at whether these two functions are the same
I have a simple and dumb question:
are these two functions the same?
$$
f(x)=x 
$$
and
$$
g(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}
$$
Obviously f and g are the same since you can simplify by x but are they really? $f$ is defined for all reals, but $g$ is not defined at $0$. I am entirely self taught so I do not know if there is a formal difference between these two, hence why I am here.

To nitpick one would need to define function first. Those two are neither of the more than three inequivalent definitions of functions that people use nowadays. Those are expressions. There are associated functions that people imply by mentioning those expressions. Since this is implied by context, there are different choices to be made. Not all give the same answer to your question.

From your last paragraph, it seems that the functions that you want to talk about are $f$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$ and mapping $x\mapsto x$ and $g$ with domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus{0}$ and mapping $x\mapsto x^2/x$. In that case, just by not having the same domain they are not the same function. However, note that the cause of this lies, primarily on agreeing which functions are you implying are being defined from those expressions.

$f(x) = x$ is not a function and nor is $g(x) = x^2/x$: they are equations that one might use in defining functions $f$ and $g$. As @ameg's comments suggest, it is common to use equations like this as if they were free-standing definitions, but the context should make it clear what the domains of the functions are expected to be (and this is often forgotten).

The notion of equality of two functions is as follows:
Two functions, $f:A\rightarrow B$, $g:X\rightarrow Y$ are equal if they satisfy the three following rules:
They have the same domain, i.e $A$ and $X$ are the same.
They have the same codomain, i.e $B$ and $Y$ are the same.
For every $a\in A$, $f(a)=g(a)$.
However, unless you define $g(0)=c$ , for some arbitrary c, then you are implicitly saying that the functions do not even have the same domain. So unless you define $g(0)$ to be some constant, then the function will fail the first condition. In fact, the functions , $f$ and $g$ will be equal only if $g(0)$ is defined to be the same as $f(0)=0$ , due to the third condition.
So in conclusion, without defining $g(0)=0$ (and specifying the domain and codomain of f and g), the functions cannot be said to be equal.
Using this definition,it is important to emphasise that you should know the domain and codomain;technically you never said the domain and codomain of the functions. If in fact $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}, g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, then in fact $f$ and $g$ are equal. (As an illustration of the definition).

@Skepta Even here, one specific definition of function is being used. It is not the only one. Other definition of functions yield different (not equivalent to this) definitions of equality of functions.
